# Prove that $\alpha$ is in the alternating group $A_n$ if and only if $\alpha^{-1}\in A_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

> Prove: $\alpha   \in A_{n}$ if and only if $\alpha ^{-1} \in A_{n}$

I know $A_{n}$ denotes an alternating group of degree $n$. Should I use the fact that $A_{n}$ is a subgroup of $S_{n}$ to start? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It depends on what facts you have available. This follows immediately from the fact that $A_n$ is a subgroup of $S_n$ (and hence is a group). Is this statement perhaps part of an exercise to show that $A_n$ (regarded as a sub*set* of $S_n$) is a sub*group*?

Comment: This is all that is given

Comment: Hint: write $\alpha$ as a product of permutations of length 2

Comment: In that case presumably one should not use that $A_n$ is a subgroup, as that would make the problem trivial. In this case, @TsemoAristide's hint is quite good.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the knowledge that $A_n$ is a subgroup of $S_n$, then this fact is immediate.

If not, you note that $\alpha\in A_n$ if, and only if $\alpha=\tau_1\cdots\tau_{2n}$ is a product of an even number of transpositions. But, $\alpha=\tau_1\cdots\tau_{2n}$ is a product of an even number of transpositions if, and only if, $\alpha^{-1}=\tau_{2n}\cdots\tau_1$ is also a product of an even number of transpositions.